# Why does this example not break avoidability?

Tags: combinatorics-on-words

Suppose we have an alphabet $E = \{x_1,x_2,...x_k\}$.
Then according to (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.05540.pdf, page 2), Zimin words are unavoidable.
How does word $w = (x_1)(x_1)(x_1)\ldots$ not violate this?

In the paper, it is mentioned that a condition is that w must be sufficiently large. What do they mean, exactly? The example above is infinite, so it must be sufficiently large.

Comment: It seems to me that your $w$ encounters all of the Zimin words, and in fact all words whatsoever.

Comment: For Zimin word Z_(n+1) = (Z_n)(x_{n+1})(Z_n), Z_1 = x_1, Z_2, Z_3... are all not met as only x_1 occurs in w, not x_2, x_3... so not all Zimin words are encountered here.

Comment: Look again at the definition of "matches" and "encounter", particularly at the part "by substituting ...". Nothing prohibits substituting $x_1$ for all the $x_k$'s in any Zimin word.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much!